I get the error: 'UIImagePickerController.InfoKey' (aka 'NSString') has no member 'editedImage'
This is the code I'm trying to use. All I get is an error:

Type 'UIImagePickerController.InfoKey' (aka 'NSString') has no member 'editedImage'.

My imports:
import UIKit
import Photos
import FirebaseAuth
import JGProgressHUD

Using:

XCode Version 16.0 (16A242d)
swift-driver version: 1.115 Apple Swift version 6.0 (swiftlang-6.0.0.9.10 clang-1600.0.26.2)

// Delegate method to handle the selection
extension RegisterViewController {
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        if let editedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage {
            print("Edited Image: \(editedImage)")
        } else if let originalImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
            print("Original Image: \(originalImage)")
        }
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    // Handle cancellation
    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}


Can't reproduce. The code, as provided (making allowances) compiles fine on my machine. Have you tried restarting the computer? Throwing out the derived data? Can you provide a [mcve]?

Try using something like: if let image = info["UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"] as? UIImage 

I've found the issue! I checked in TARGETS > Swift Language Version -> And I was using Swift 4 in the project. Changed it to Swift 6 and done!
I realized because of this error in Xcode: 'jpegData(compressionQuality:)' has been renamed to 'UIImageJPEGRepresentation(::)'
It was telling me to use an older version, which made no sense.
